# finding determinant using elementary matrices

Tags: determinant

use elementary matrices to find the determinant of the matrix A

A = (2 5 -1),(-1 -1 5), (3 7 -3)

solution I found:

```
-36
```

Comment: To count trace, determinant, etc. I suggest you the site http://matrix.reshish.com/ You can also find detailed solutions, etc.

Comment: The correct answer is $0$. Show us what you did and we can find your mistake.